# Ejecución con Gherkin - cucumber - ExceptionInInitializerError:Xtream

Tags: selenium, java-8, java-ee, cucumber

Estoy intentando ejecutar solo el código de Gherkin y me está dando un `ExceptionInInitializerError` de Xtream.
Este es el código de feature:

```
Feature: prueba

  Scenario: prueba
    Given estoy en la pagina de innocv "https://www.prueba.com/"
    When hago click Como lo hacemos
    Then hacemos scroll en tipos de sectores
    And validamos cada tipo de sector
```

Este sería de Java:

```
public class Prueba {
    
    @Given("^estoy en la pagina de innocv \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void estoy_en_la_pagina_de_innocv(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        
    }

    @When("^hago click Como lo hacemos$")
    public void hago_click_Como_lo_hacemos() throws Throwable {
       
    }

    @Then("^hacemos scroll en tipos de sectores$")
    public void hacemos_scroll_en_tipos_de_sectores() throws Throwable {
        
    }

    @And("^validamos cada tipo de sector$")
    public void validamos_cada_tipo_de_sector() throws Throwable {
      
    }
}
```

Y ejecutando el feature ya añadido los metodos en java, me aparece este error:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
> at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:574)
> at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:530)
> at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
> at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
> at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
> at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
> at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
> at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
> at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
> at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
> at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
> at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
> at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
> at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @34d2e626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado su problema es por sintaxis posiblemente por la version de libreria que esta utilizando.

Le mostraré une ejemplo con cucumber 7

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Scenario Outline: Ingresar login
    When ingreso a tu cuenta
    And banca y seguros
  Then se visualizan los campos del login "<rut>" y "<clave>"

@When("ingreso a tu cuenta")
public void ingreso_a_tu_cuenta() throws Throwable {

}

@And("banca y seguros")
public void banca_y_seguros() throws Throwable {

}

@Then("se visualizan los campos del login {string} y {string}")
public void se_visualizan_los_campos_del_login(String rut,String clave)throws Throwable {
}
```